# Printing an Abstract Syntax Tree

Tags: c, tree, printf, abstract-syntax-tree

I am attempting to use an Abstract Syntax Tree to take a Reverse Polish Notation equation and change it to its equivalent infix form. Below is the structure of the AST and the `print_table` we had originally used to print a tree.

```
struct tnode {
  char *datum;
  struct tnode *left;
  struct tnode *right;
};

void print_table(struct tnode *AST) {
  if(AST != NULL) {
    print_table(AST->left);
    printf("%s", AST->datum);
    print_table(AST->right);
  }
}
```

However, this prints the tree from the top down. For example, if given `5 4 + 3 -`, it will return `-3+45`. What I want for it to print is `5+4-3`, essentially printing the left most child, then it's parent node, and the right child of that parent node until all elements of the tree have been printed.
How might I go about doing this?

Comment: How is the `5 4 + 3 -` would be stored in the `tnode`?

Comment: The root of the tree is the -, the left child of that is the +, the right child is the 3. 
The left child of the + is the 5, the right child is the 4.

Comment: That printing function appears correct. I'll bet a cookie that your parsing function is incorrect. A Racket version of your code works: http://pasterack.org/pastes/29421

Answer (score 0):

```
struct tnode*
build_tree(struct snode **S)
{
  struct tnode* root;
  if (*S == NULL)
    return NULL;

  char *top = peek(*S);

  if (is_operator(top))
    {
      root = create_node(top);
      pop(S);
      root->right = build_tree(S);
      pop(S);
      root->left = build_tree(S);
      return root;
    }

  root = create_node(top);

  return root;
}
```

I think your problem is with how you build your tree. The print function should work for you. Here is a way to build the tree. I'm in your class. If you want to meet up and work on the project together I would be down.